# Python using getattr to call function with variable parameters

Tags: python, function, variables, parameters, getattr

I'm using getattr to call different functions depending on a variable.

Im doing something like that:

```
getattr(foo, bar) ()
```

That works, calling functions like foo.bar()

My problem is that I have 'bar' functions and I want to call it with different parameters. For example:

```
def f1() :
  pass

def f2(param1) :
  pass

def f3(param1,param2) :
  pass
```

so 'bar' could be f1, f2, or f3

I tried this:
assumming that params is a list which contains all parameters needed for the 'bar' function

```
getattr(foo, bar) (for p in params :)
```

I watching for a "clean" solution, with no needed to watch the length on the params variable

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
getattr(foo, bar)(*params)
```

This works if `params` is a list or a tuple.  The elements from `params` will be unpacked in order:

```
params=(1, 2)
foo(*params)
```

is equivalent to:

```
params=(1, 2)
foo(params[0], params[1])
```

If there are keyword arguments, you can do that too.

```
getattr(foo, bar)(*params, **keyword_params)
```

where `keyword_params` is a dictionary.

Also, This answer is really independent of `getattr`.  It will work for any function/method.

Comment: I know OP didn't ask specifically, but I'd add `**kwargs` too, just so he doesn't end up with hard to track down bugs later on should he attempt to use keyword arguments.

Answer (score 7):

This is very simple in Python 3. Here is the example:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def m(self, x):
        print(f"{self.name} called with param '{x}'")
        return

ci = C("Joe", 10)
print(C)
print(ci)
print(C.m)
print(ci.m)
print(getattr(ci,'m'))
getattr(ci,'m')('arg')
```

---

```
<class '__main__.C'>
<__main__.C object at 0x000001AF4025FF28>
<function C.m at 0x000001AF40272598>
<bound method C.m of <__main__.C object at 0x000001AF4025FF28>>
<bound method C.m of <__main__.C object at 0x000001AF4025FF28>>
Joe called with param 'arg'
```

Note that [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) is from the [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#module-builtins) module, takes in our case the two parameters, the class instance `ci` and the string representing the name of the function.

We could also define the defult value for the parameter.

```
def m(self, x=None):
    print(f"{self.name} caled with param '{x}'")
    return
```

In which case we may call:

```
getattr(ci,'m')()
```

Comment: This helped me. I understood it like... `getattr(object_on_which_the_function_is_to_be_called, function_name_as_a_string)(parameters_to_be_passed_to_the_function)`. This will result into a function call `function_name_as_a_string(parameters_to_be_passed_to_the_function)`. Not sure if my understanding is very correct, but it worked and that's how I perceived it..

Comment: @manpikin I think you mean the first argument should be "object **from** which the function is to be called", not "on".
You give the function an object name and an attribute name as a string and it tries to give you back the value of the object's attribute, if existing. If not, you can give it the third argument, a default value.

Comment: Thank you @prosti. It worked for me. Just simple call 'getattr(Object instance, methodName in String)(parameters) Awesome

Answer (score 1):

A maybe more readable way, which is better for handling exceptions:

```
class foo:
    def method_xy(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f'args:{args}, kwargs:{kwargs}')


bar = 'method_xy'
xi = foo()
try:
    func_name = getattr(xi, bar)
except AttributeError:
    # handle missing method
    pass

args = ['bla1', 'bla2']
kwargs = {'a1': 1, 'a2': 2}

try:
    result = func_name(*args, **kwargs)
except TypeError:
    # handle Problems with arguments
    pass
```

Comment: This is much harder to read and understand than `getattr(ci,'m')()`