# How to access a Python function using it's __name__?

Tags: python, python-2.7, function

I have a function *func* :

```
def func(a):
    print a

func.__name_ = "My_Function"
```

To get the name of the function I will just do `func.__name__`. 
But is there a way to call func() by using its name i.e. "My_Function"?

Edit: There are going to be large number of functions for which this has to be done. Is there any better solution apart from keeping a mapping of function.**name** to the function. ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this? It's likely an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). The `__name__` is just a label, it's not the same as doing `My_Function = func`.

Comment: If you have name of function and name of your module/class, you can use `getattr` to get function and invoke it. Have a look at this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781265/python-using-getattr-to-call-function-with-variable-parameters)

Comment: If you are desperate: `[f for _,f in locals().items() if callable(f) and f.__name__=='My_Function' ][0]('Hello')`. Do try this at home, not in production. Use other option as Deepspace/johrsharpe suggested.

Answer (score 5):

It will be much easier to use  a dictionary:

```
def func():
    print('func')

func_dict = {"My_Function": func}

func_dict["My_Function"]()
# 'func'
```

Comment: I think it should be `func_dict[func.__name__]()`?

Comment: @Laszlowaty No. This example never sets `func.__name__`.

Comment: @Laszlowaty: No, because, if `func` is already there why bother accessing it via `func_dict`?

Comment: Well you don't need to set `func.__name__`. But I think I didn't understand the question correctly, sorry :)

Comment: @Laszlowaty You can do `func_dict = {func.__name__: func} ; func_dict[func.__name__]()` but I don't see the point.

Comment: @DeepSpace I have edited the question
"There are going to be large number of functions for which this has to be done. Is there any better solution apart from keeping a mapping of function.name to the function. ?"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to access functions that are defined in global scope (not part of any class/object):

```
def foo():
    print "foo"

def bar():
    print "bar"

foo.__name__ = "1"
bar.__name__ = "2"

# locals().items() will return the current local symbol table, which is an iterable and 
# it contains the globally defined functions.
symbol_table = locals().items()

# we will generate a list of functions that their __name__ == "1"
one_functions = [value for key, value in symbol_table if callable(value) and value.__name__ == "1"]

# now we can call the first item on the list - foo()
one_functions[0]()
```