# Could someone please explain how the function getattr(Object, function) works when passed variables?

Tags: python-3.x, function, variables, args, getattr

So I am working on some hackerrank questions and someone posted the following snippet of code as part of a solution and I was curious if someone could explain it to me please?

```
getattr(l, parts[0])(*(map(int, parts[1:])))
```

In the following thread:

[Python using getattr to call function with variable parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781265/python-using-getattr-to-call-function-with-variable-parameters)

Mgilson mentioned this can be done for any function/method and I became confused.

In the getattr() documentation I found no information of passing *args after the function and so was confused. Is this method generally applicable to all functions? If so could someone please provide a few basic examples and explain why this is true?

I would greatly appreciate this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't find this in `getattr`'s documentation because passing
arguments to a function using the `*` operator is a totally different
thing.

This code:

```py
l = "my_fun"
getattr(l, parts[0])(*(map(int, parts[1:])))
```

is actually equivalent to:

```py
l = "my_fun"
fun = getattr(l, parts[0])
fun(*(map(int, parts[1:])))
```

You get the function called `my_fun`, then call this function.  `map(int, parts[1:])` maps items of `parts[1:]` to integers and then the `*`
operator unpacks these integer to use them as arguments of `fun`.

So this solution works as long as the function called has a number of
arguments equal to `len(parts[1:])`.

Here is another example with two files.

```py
#  my_pack/__init__.py

def fun1(x):
    print('x =', x)

def fun2(x, y):
    print('x =', x, ', y =', y)


#  test.py
import my_pack

args = [1]
fun = getattr(my_pack, 'fun1')
fun(*args)

#  equivalent solution
fun = getattr(my_pack, 'fun1')(*args)

args = [1, 2]
fun = getattr(my_pack, 'fun2')(*args)
```

What @mgilson said is that this principle of calling a function
without listing explicitly all its parameters but using the `*`
operator is totally independent from `getattr`.  As for instance here
where I don't use `getattr`:

```py
def my_cool_func(a, b, c):
   print(a, b, c)

my_cool_func(*[1, 2, 3])  #  prints "1 2 3"
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, it proved very helpful!